# I intend to run a periodic routine. Which way could guarantee more precise delay? `nanosleep` or `signal through timer_create, timer_settime`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I intend to run a periodic routine. 
Which way could guarantee more precise delay? `nanosleep` or  `timer_create, timer_settime`?

The type of their input argument is same(`struct itimerspec`).

**It would be better if there could be a description about the internal implenmetation in your answer.**

Could anybody help to make it clear for me?
I would be thankful for any hint on this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214462/discussion-on-question-by-sunshilong369-i-intend-to-run-a-periodic-routine-whic).

Answer (score 1):

The kernel uses the same clock source for both of them under linux.
And unless you're using a real-time OS, there are no guarantees of precise timing anyway.
So neither of them could provide you a precise delay.